# Getting error: "Validation of viewState MAC failed."

Tags: c#

I get the error:
"Validation of viewstate MAC failed. If this application is hosted by a Web Farm or cluster ensure that `<machineKey>` configuration specifies the same validationKey and validation algorithm. AutoGenerate cannot be used in a cluster."

I don't use this error if I do not go through Load Balancer. If I go through Load Balancer, I get this error about 50% of the time. Load Balancer has sticky sessions.

My config file is like this:
    validationKey='2EEA416CEFC6D6BE856ED57B97FB9CA7DFACE17C073125949A1D682C80A44BB2AD887DDDC13DBFB0954F1000FEE5757E99693F222F8E28CAA2E6DAB8C4F99E0C'
    decryptionKey='877478B2F33A74226ABEF55FDCC1A76E43F1BBEA6241A592'
    validation='SHA1' />

```
<pages enableViewStateMac="false">
```

so, I already have enableViewStateMac="false". How can I make the sporadic errors to go away?

Answer (score 0):

You need all servers affected by the load-balancer to use the same machine key, that way when a viewstate generated to server 1 and is posted to server 2, server 2 can authenticate the viewstate because both server 1 and 2 use the same key.

more information: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc731979%28v=ws.10%29.aspx

edit:

Also if you're using some CSRF protection, you must ensure there's a way to persist that information between servers. (Some CSRF protection schemes specify a viewstate key).